# Reverse proxy converting session cookie to path prefix

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm working on a problem where some users need to create multiple sessions to a web app.  A browser can only hold one session cookie at a time (without awkward browser hacks, which said users are not savvy enough to deal with) and I want to solve this problem by creating a reverse proxy where the first piece of the URL is actually the session cookie to use when contacting the back-end app.

Here's an illustration of the idea:

```
Client Request:
GET https://myproxy/

Proxy Request:
GET https://example.com/

Application response:
302 https://example.com/welcome
Set-Cookie: session=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP

Proxy Response
302 https://myproxy/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP/welcome

Client Request
GET https://myproxy/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP/welcome

Proxy Request
GET https://example.com/welcome
Cookie: session=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```

Hopefully that demonstrates the idea.  I know how to accomplish this for a single static prefix using Apache with ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse, and mod_proxy_html, but this doesn't seem possible with a dynamic prefix pulled out of a cookie.

I could write this up as a full-blown application, but I'm wondering if any web server (apache, nginx, etc) has some built-in way to configure this behavior?  Maybe with mod_perl?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible with nginx, here is an idea:

```
map $upstream_cookie_session $prefix {
    ~^(.*)$    $1/;
}

upstream backend {
    server    example.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myproxy.example.com;
    # other ssl parameters here (key, certificate etc.)

    # root URI client request
    location = / {
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        # other HTTP headers setup here
        proxy_redirect https://example.com(/.*)$ https://myproxy.example.com/$prefix$1;
        proxy_cookie_path / /$prefix;
        proxy_pass https://backend;
    }

    # prefixed URI client request, assuming prefix is the session id
    location ~ ^/(?<session>[^/]+)(?<path>/.*) {
        # rewrite URI and remove the prefix path
        rewrite ^ $path break;
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        # other HTTP headers setup here
        proxy_set_header Cookie "session=$session";
        proxy_redirect https://example.com(/.*)$ https://myproxy.example.com/$prefix$1;
        proxy_cookie_path / /$prefix;
        proxy_pass https://backend;
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just an idea, it should be tested and there are can be other caveats (or this would not work at all). This configuration would not clear the `session` cookie returned from upstream, but would rewrite it's `path` attribute, so several `session` cookies with different paths should not interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks!  I think you hit a key point here; the prefix doesn't need to be the actual value of the cookie, it could be any random number that causes the real cookie's path component to get rewritten.  The browser would then just manage a collection of cookies with path prefixes, and send one based on the URL.